# Kendo UI TreeView Checkbox Select All

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I had a similar situation like this [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IlOHOYuS).

1. When I click on "Select All" on top of the table, it will check all the checkbox's below with different ID name on kendoTreeView?
2. Why Im not able to check on parents node. Example if check the name "*Steven Buchanan*" all the child is check.

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IlOHOYuS)

Answer (score 1):

I already found the answer.

1. I need to create onchange function on "Select All" checkbox. [Source in here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/treeview-uncheck-check-all-nodes)

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="chbAll" value="Uncheck" class="k-checkbox" onchange="chbAllCheck()" />
```

```js
function chbAllCheck() {
  var checkButtonValue = $("#chbAll").val();

  if(checkButtonValue == "Uncheck"){
    $("#treeview .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    $("#treeview_1 .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    $("#treeview_2 .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
    $("#chbAll").val("Check");
  } else {
    $("#treeview .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
    $("#treeview_1 .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
    $("#treeview_2 .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change")
    $("#chbAll").val("Uncheck");
  }
}
```

2. Need to replace this line `checkboxes: { checkChildren: true },` . [Source in here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/configuration/checkboxes)

Here a [working demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IlOHOYuS/2) in case someone needed